# Preencher Combobox com base em outro

Tags: javascript, ajax, combobox

Estou realizando projeto de um site na linguagem Ruby on Rails. Estou criando toda parte do JavaScript agora.

Tenho uma dúvida javascript em uma aplicação Ruby

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
ajaxBar = (unity_id) ->
    $('select#product_bundle_bar_id').empty()
    $.ajax
      url: "populate_bars/#{unity_id}"
      type: "POST"
      dataType: 'json'
      success: (data) ->
        $('select#product_bundle_bar_id').append $("<option>").attr("value", "").text("Selecione o bar")
        bar_value = $("#product_bundle_bar_value").val()
        $.each data, (i, object) ->
          $('select#product_bundle_bar_id').append $("<option>").attr("value", object.id).text(object.name)
          $("select#product_bundle_bar_id option[value=#{bar_value}]").attr('selected', 'selected') if unity_id?
        return
```

Neste site existe vários combobox que tem Regional, Unidade, Bar e Totem. Ao escolher a regional ele me retorna as unidades localizadas dentro da regional, quando escolho a unidade ele me retorna todos os bares localizados nesta regional.

Cada bar apresenta apenas um Totem, por isso gostaria de fazer que o usuário ao escolher o Bar o Totem já fosse preenchido automaticamente com o nome do Totem que está associado ao Bar.

Depois do código AjaxBar tenho

```
ajaxTotem = (bar_id) ->
    $('select#product_bundle_totem_id').empty()
    $.ajax
      url: "populate_totems/#{bar_id}"
      type: "POST"
      dataType: 'json'
      success: (data) ->
        $('select#product_bundle_totem_id').append $("<option>").attr("value", "").text("Selecione o totem")
        totem_value = $("#product_bundle_totem_value").val()
        $.each data, (i, object) ->
          $('select#product_bundle_totem_id').append $("<option>").attr("value", object.id).text(object.name)
          $("select#product_bundle_totem_id option[value=#{totem_value}]").attr('selected', 'selected') if bar_id?
        return
```

O código do AjaxTotem me faz retornar o Totem de acordo com o Bar, só que ele não preenche automaticamente, o usuário tem que escolher.

Como faço isso? Para que ao escolher o Bar, o Totem faça uma busca e preencha automaticamente de acordo com o Id e Nome do Totem localizado no bar?